# How to seed multiple many-to-many relationships with different pivot data in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, factory, seeding, laravel-8

I know that I can use the `hasAttached` method to [create many-to-many relationships with pivot data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#many-to-many-relationships) in Laravel 8:

```
  Meal::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->hasAttached(Ingredient::factory()->count(3), ['gram' => 100])
        ->create();
```

Is there **any convenient wa**y (other than writing a custom for-loop) **to seed the pivot table with random data for each attached entry?** I want the `'gram'` to be a random number for each of the created relationships. I tried the following but the `rand` expression just gets evaluated once and fills the pivot table with the same entry for each relationship:

```
Meal::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->hasAttached(Ingredient::factory()->count(3), ['gram' => rand(1,100]) //not working
        ->create();
```

Edit: I basically want to achieve

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $meal = Meal::factory()->create();

        for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
            $ingredient = Ingredient::factory()->create();
            $meal->ingredients()->save($ingredient, ['gram' => rand(5, 250)]);
        }
    }
```

with Laravel's fluent factory methods.

Comment: I don't have anything to try it right now, but does this works? `->hasAttached(Ingredient::factory()->count(3), fn() => ['gram' => rand(1,100])`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier it does! Thank you very much. You might want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call a method like this `method(rand(1,100))` the `rand` is evaluated before the call. It will be the same as doing `method(59)`

Fortunately, Laravel allow you to use a callback to re-evaluate the parameter on each call,

```php
Meal::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->hasAttached(Ingredient::factory()->count(3), fn => ['gram' => rand(1,100)])
        ->create();
```

---

*If you use a PHP version bellow 7.4 you won't be able to use arrow function and you will have to do like this*

```php
Meal::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->hasAttached(Ingredient::factory()->count(3), function () { 
            return ['gram' => rand(1,100)]; 
        })
        ->create();
```